# ValueError: operation parameter must be str - Python SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am experiencing an error while I am trying to insert some data into a SQLite3 table.

```
for tag in subject["tags"]:
    query = ("""
    INSERT INTO Tags (tag_text, tag_category, tag_start, tag_end, tag_doc_id, tag_subject_id, tag_id)
    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    """, (str(tag["tag_text"]), str(tag["tag_label"]), str(tag["tag_start"]), str(tag["tag_end"]), str(doc_id), str(subject["subject_id"]), str(tag["tag_id"])))

    c.execute(query)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: operation parameter must be str
```

I tried to fix the parenthesis (which I think might be the problem), but from other answers it seems they are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query and parameters are separate arguments to `c.execute()`. The query is a string, the parameters are an iterable.

```
query = """
INSERT INTO Tags (tag_text, tag_category, tag_start, tag_end, tag_doc_id, tag_subject_id, tag_id)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
"""
params = (str(tag["tag_text"]), str(tag["tag_label"]), str(tag["tag_start"]), str(tag["tag_end"]), str(doc_id), str(subject["subject_id"]), str(tag["tag_id"]))

c.execute(query, params)
```

If you want to put them together, you need to spread it when calling the method.

```
query = ("""
INSERT INTO Tags (tag_text, tag_category, tag_start, tag_end, tag_doc_id, tag_subject_id, tag_id)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
""", (str(tag["tag_text"]), str(tag["tag_label"]), str(tag["tag_start"]), str(tag["tag_end"]), str(doc_id), str(subject["subject_id"]), str(tag["tag_id"])))

c.execute(*query)
```

Comment: Thanks. My query is inside a `for loop` and when I execute with your changes I get: `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Don't forget about `connection.commit()`